# In Xcode Is the @rpath defined by "Build Settings" -> "Runpath Search Paths"?

Tags: rpath

I know what @rpath does in a binary. I am trying to understand where in Xcode @rpath is defined. In Xcode Is the @rpath defined by "Build Settings" -> "Runpath Search Paths" ?